# What to do when CI won't run in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval

I used `exp(confint(m))` for models and for most models it worked. I got the following error for one model. Any ideas as to if there's something I can do so I can get CI?

```
Error in zetafun(np, ns) : profiling detected new, lower deviance
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In zeta(shiftpar, start = opt[seqpar1][-w]) :
  slightly lower deviances (diff=-2.62048e-11) detected
2: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  Last two rows have identical or NA .zeta values: using minstep
3: In zetafun(np, ns) :
  slightly lower deviances (diff=-1.28665e-10) detected
4: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  Last two rows have identical or NA .zeta values: using minstep
5: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  Last two rows have identical or NA .zeta values: using minstep
```

Full code used is:

```
lr1.9b<- glmer(resuser ~ scale(PropVuln_1) + gender + (1|schoolID), data = ATIVforR191113, family = binomial)
tidy(lr1.9b)
exp(confint(lr1.9b))
```

Comment: Ben Bolker wrote glmer.  He shows up now and again.  He should know

Comment: Explaining that you used R is not redundant.

Comment: Please offer a small reproducible example.

Comment: Not my answer, sorry but I've not reputation to comment.
Look at these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120614/error-when-estimating-ci-for-glmm-using-confint
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485322/estimating-ci-using-confint-for-glmm-leads-to-error-in-zetafun-np-ns